# mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES") doesn't show my database

Tags: php, mysql, database, show

I am testing a local page using xampp. Searching how to fix a "No database selected" mysql error lead me to testing this out:

```
mysql_connect('localhost') or die ("Connect error");

$res = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
    echo $row[0], '<br/>';
}
```

But that query only shows two results: "information_schema" and "test". Which I don't understand cause on phpMyAdmin I can see all this databases:

cdcol, information_schema, mysql, performance_schema, phpmyadmin, test, xxxxxxxx_db (the one I created) and webauth

And (on phpMyAdmin) I can see that root has privileges to this database. Root has no password.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

I have an actual site online, I use mysql_connect and such to connect to the database... But I had to reinstall xampp and dreamweaver and everything on my PC and then had to download the database and the whole site cause I need to test some things locally. I can't afforrd to change the mysql querys and use PDO for now, maybe later when I have the time.

My main problem is the connection, it doesn't work, It prints "No database selected". I don't know why it doesn't find my xxxxxxxx_db database.

Comment: use PDO as mysql_* is deprecated.

Comment: What does this print: `echo ini_get('mysql.default_username'), ini_get('mysql.default_password');`?

Comment: Should be `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: @iBrazilian2 PDO printed my databases. I guess I'm gonna try conecting via PDO and not mysql_*... It used to work before though, a few months ago before I changed PCs.

Comment: @DanFromGermany That prints absolutely nothing :(
Mr.Alien That shows the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you said your default config is empty, so when you connect to mysql, you have to pass the username to the function:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ("Connect error");
```

You should also keep the connectino resource in a variable and pass it to the query:

```
$res = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES", $connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
    echo $row[0], '<br/>';
}
```

If you cannot rewrite all the statements, well, you SHOULD sooner or later you will have even more trouble.

Comment: Passing the username (root) works perfectly. Wow, I didn't know I was connecting to nothing, that's why It only showed two databases. I actually thought I was connecting to root. Thanks a lot.

@JenniferDias solution also works.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

if ($res = mysqli_query($link, 'SHOW DATABASES')) {
    echo 'Connected.';
} else {
    echo 'Error occurred', mysqli_error($link);
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) {
    echo $row[0], '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: It prints this:

Connected
Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\_____________________.php on line 13

Comment: try this one
Or use mysqli_fetch_array()

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() works! thanks Jennifer. Problem solved, now on to the other problems :P Cheers

Comment: Really great improvement Martin Bean.